# How do I tell R to give me only the values that are greater than 1 in a table output (i.e. have multiple terms)?

Tags: r, csv

I have a large dataset with many entries and I want to see which company has multiple entries. A portion of the output from the table function of the variable I want to look at is below. Instead I want a table with just the entries greater than 1. For example, I want to say something like `table(dataset$var > 1)` but this obviously does not work.

```
                                                                                                                        Accretive Health 
                                                                                                                                         1 
                                                                                                                                Accuprint  
                                                                                                                                         1 
                                                                                  ACS, Affiliated Computer Services, Inc., A Xerox Company 
                                                                                                                                         1 
                                                                                                                                AdminisTEP 
                                                                                                                                         1 
                                                                              Administracion de Seguros de Salud - Triple S Salud Inc (BA) 
                                                                                                                                         2 
                                                                                                                                 ADPI-West 
                                                                                                                                         1 
                                                                                                      ADT LLC Group Health & Welfare Plan 
                                                                                                                                         1 
                                                                                                         Adult & Pediatric Dermatology, PC
```

Comment: You can filter your data frame like this dataframe[dataset$var > 1,]

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
x <- table(dataset$var)
x[x > 1]
```

Or a one-liner using `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) x > 1, table(dataset$var))
```

Using `dplyr`, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% count(var) %>% filter(n > 1)
```